# Facebook SDK for Unity - URL Scheme

Tags: ios, authentication, unity-game-engine, url-scheme, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have an issue with Facebook SDK for Unity.

I am trying to log without being prompted by facebook's login pop-up, and log with the account in iOS settings / Facebook App instead.

I get an error:

2014-07-07 17:27:03.889 m3fb[466:60b] FBSDKLog: Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorize, fb250XXXXXX1234fb250XXXXXX1234 is not registered as a URL Scheme.

Facebook app id, bundle id and app name are set correctly ( I made sure to copy-paste ), and I have set up the URL Scheme: "fb" + appID.

Answer (score 0):

I use Facebook SDK for Facebook tasks and Prime31 plugin for Twitter.
Apparently I had to register the URL scheme in Prime31 only, otherwise it did not work properly.